# How to force Google App Engine [python] to use SSL (https)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, https

I write a web app on Google App Engine using Python.

Users can access my site at **http**://[youraccount].appspot.com and **https**://[youraccount].appspot.com

How do I redirect the ***http*** traffic to the ***https*** site.

In other words, how do I force this site to use **`SSL(https)`**  for **security** purpose (and for better SEO)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add a `secure` parameter to the `app.yaml` file.

```
handlers:
- url: /youraccount/.*
  script: accounts.py
  login: required
  secure: always
```

See [Configuring Secure URLs in app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Secure_URLs)

> Google App Engine supports secure connections via HTTPS for URLs using
>   the `*.appspot.com` domain. When a request accesses a URL using HTTPS,
>   and that URL is configured to use HTTPS in the app.yaml file, *both the
>   request data and the response data are encrypted by the sender before
>   they are transmitted, and decrypted by the recipient after they are
>   received*. Secure connections are useful for protecting customer data,
>   such as contact information, passwords, and private messages.

Comment: It's worth noting that default response code is `302` and you can change response code by using `redirect_http_response_code: 301` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For a Django project running on Google App Engine in the **Flexible** Environment, setting `secure: always` in app.yaml doesn't work [[Google Cloud docs]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-requests-are-handled#forcing_https_connections).

Instead, in my `settings.py` file, I added the following [[Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/middleware/#http-strict-transport-security):

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 31536000
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
```

Note that `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER` is needed because the servers sit behind a load balancer.

Comment: Strange, that this one have -1 votes.This is the correct answer if you are willing to force `build_absolute_uri()` function to return HTTPS URLs for django app under flexible env. Thanks!

Comment: I would give 100 upvotes, if it would be possible. This worked like a magic without pain! Thank you!!!!